# freemarker looping sequence error

Tags: freemarker

I'm trying to retrieve data with this code

```
<tests>
<#if tests?exists>
<#list tests as object >
<test>
<#list object?keys as key >
    <${key}>
        <#if object[key]?exists>
            <#if object[key]?is_hash> HASH  
                <#elseif object[key]?is_sequence>                   
                    <#list object[key] as hashKey>

                    </#list>
            <#else> ${object[key]}</#if><#else>null
        </#if>
    </${key}>
</#list>
</test>
</#list>
</#if>
```

but getting an error `?size is unsupported for: freemarker.ext.beans.SimpleMethodModel`

but `<#elseif object[key]?is_sequence>  sequence` returns sequence. As I understand means that my `object[key]` is a sequence.
Any ideas?

Comment: There's no `?size` or `?is_sequence` in your sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error occurs because as a result of some historical mishap, Java methods are sequences (with the built in `ObjectWrapper`-s, that is), but they don't implement `?size`. (They are sequences so that `foo.m[x]` is equivalent with `foo.m(x)`). Add `&& !something?is_method` to the condition avoid this.